# Draw a special hollow square shape in android

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-drawable, shapes

I want to draw the white shape that you can see in the image below, but I have no idea to how do that.
It is a square with top right and top left radius, and there is a little cut off on the left side with a circle on it.
[the shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHS1B.png)

I want to use this shape as a background for a view.
I have tried many ways such as XML shapes, but... .

PS: I'm really sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing you could do, is draw this shape in Adobe Ilustrator, or any other vector image tool of your choice, save it as an SVG file and convert it to an Android Drawable.

Vector program: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)

Converter: [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

Greets from Germany.